# recurrence tree diagram of () = ( −1) + (/2) +

Tags: algorithm

Use a recurrence tree to determine a good asymptotic upper bound on the recurrence () = ( −1) + (/2) +.

please post the answer if any one knows

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:  http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.cgi?%20%5CLarge%20T(n)=%7BO(2%5E%7BO(logn)%7D)%7D

I found the answer and solution methods in [this quora webpage](https://www.quora.com/What-would-be-the-recursion-tree-for-T-n-T-n%E2%88%921-+T-frac-n-2-+n).